# How to implement IPX/SPX transport protocol from scratch on Windows 7?

Tags: windows, networking, protocols, driver

I would like to implement IPX/SPX network protocol on Windows 7. I've installed WDK and grabbed all the needed IPX/SPX RFC but I don't know what to do after with the WDK?
What are your suggestions?

Thx.

Comment: Doesn't Windows aleady have IPX drivers? Or Novell?

Comment: Since Vista windows removed IPX/SPX protocol... Of course i can install Novel (work very bad on windows 7). But i prefer devel my own driver to update my skills.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WinDDK has a sample protocol driver at src\network\ndis\ndisprot . You can use it as a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

Various years later...

I found this IPXWrapper which is a wrapper library which emulates IPX support while tunneling the packets over UDP

About IPXWrapper:
https://www.solemnwarning.net/ipxwrapper/

Source - Github:
https://github.com/solemnwarning/ipxwrapper